# Forcing Doxygen (C) to warn if macros or enums are undocumented

Tags: c, doxygen

Is there any doxygen option to make sure Doxygen checks if all enums (and enum members) and macros are documented?

I have doxygen (**v1.8.11**) up and running, but it will only throw warnings for missing function documentation.

**EDIT**: I added some source code to show what I mean according to a request. Since the Doxyfile is quite long, I added it using pastebin. I also had to edit out some details but the main issue remains.

I would like Doxygen to tell me that

1. The enum charger_connection_state_t is not documented
2. The members of the very same enum are not documented
3. The defines at the top should all be documented
4. If I remove the documentation from the function call, Doxygen complains about an undocumented function, so the general configuration at least seems to be somewhat ok.

I remember getting errors flagged for undocumented enum members, but I'm not quite sure if I remember that correctly.

Just to make it clear, all of there are actually also used outside the module.

```
#ifndef BATTERY_INDICATOR_H_
#define BATTERY_INDICATOR_H_

#define BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_EMPTY           15
#define BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_LOW             20
#define BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_MEDIUM          59
#define BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_MEDIUM_HIGH     79
#define BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_FULL            95  //!< Everything above 95 [%] will be indicated as fully charged

typedef enum {
    NO_CHARGER,
    CHARGER_CONNECTED
} charger_connection_state_t;


//! This function drives the state machine
void battery_indicator_sm_run(void);

#endif /* BATTERY_INDICATOR_H_ */enter code here
```

Doxyfile
http://pastebin.com/0GLzHkp3

Comment: Can you show some code that causes the problem, the Doxyfile and the version of doxygen.

Comment: @albert: You're correct, I should have done that already. Just did so.

Comment: Always nice to yse the -s flag when generation / updating a Doxyfile for usage by other (comment is removed).

Comment: Ar you sure that your file is included in the documentation? I've added /** \file */ and got the messages: aa.h:6: warning: Member BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_EMPTY (macro definition) of file aa.h is not documented.
aa.h:7: warning: Member BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_LOW (macro definition) of file aa.h is not documented.
aa.h:8: warning: Member BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_MEDIUM (macro definition) of file aa.h is not documented.
aa.h:9: warning: Member BATTERY_INDICATOR_BATTERY_LEVEL_MEDIUM_HIGH (macro definition) of file aa.h is not documented.

Comment: and (as the comment box was too small):
aa.h:12: warning: Member charger_connection_state_t (enumeration) of file aa.h is not documented.

Comment: Do I need to add the @file directive to every file (the .c and the .h as well?) so that Doxygen considers this file? If so, could you formulate your comment as an answer as this seems to solve the problem (just tried it)

Comment: @albert: Could you formulate that as an answer?